# How to create a virtual table or how to order by date in same row

Tags: php, sql

Hi i have this in my database.

```
id | status1 | status2 | time1 | time2 | time3  | time4  | time5   | userid | itemuid
 1 |    2    |    1    | 000001| 000003| 000008 |   0    | 000099  |   15   |   620
 2 |    2    |    1    | 000002| 000004| 000001 |   0    | 000002  |   620  |   15
```

Now i need to echo some notifications the problem is time is in the same row.. so its a big huge problem to get this in order for example my conditions would look like

```
if ($actualuser == $userid && $status1==2)
echo  notification 
echo time4

if ($actualuser == $userid && $status2==1)
echo  notification 
echo time2
```

This goes insinde a for each loop and the only problem is i need to echo from latest(newest) to oldest, like the example below... In this examples the idea would set or Order all the times as it was just one time columns.. is this posibble?

```
item id1 time(000099) 
item id1 time(000008)
etc
item id1 time(000001)
item id1 time(0)
item id2 time(0)
```

how can i do this? Bye the way this 2 conditions are just for example.. i have like 4 or 6 conditions using the same format, but maybe i cant do this this way.. what can i do to set notifications for this...

thanks.. Im lost

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem. You say that you want to order by date in same row but you dont have a date in your table. Some datelaid example of how you want your data would be great. Do you want to have the columns time1 to time5 in a row, is that it?

Comment: I have detailed some more info in my question.. pls check again.. there is an example now on what i need , if is still unclear.. i will try to be more explicit.

Comment: So you want to organize those values horizontally? I'm not sure if theres a strightforward way of doing that, this is not what databases were designed for. If instead you had a `1 to N` relationship it would not only be easy to accomplish, but also make it possible for each of your records to have as many dates related to them as you want.

Comment: @Havenard said everithing you need, but as you already have your table, to do what you want, you gonna need `UNION` on those columns and do a order by statement

Comment: Yeah, but this approach would be costly to the DBMS. In this situation it would be easier to just organize them in the application.

Comment: Ok maybe for some actions i can create a new table.. but for comments for example.. a statusid is enough to get the notifications working, cause actually is bassed only in two dates, and you just can see 1.  The problem is if i create a new table i have to move all, right? and even if i do i have to insert a row per each action? isnt that to much data for my db? i was trying to optimize space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, As I said in comments you need to do as folow:

```
select t.*, t2.times from yourtable t, (
    select id, time1 times from yourtable union
    select id, time2 from yourtable union
    select id, time3 from yourtable union
    select id, time4 from yourtable union
    select id, time5 from yourtable ) t2
 where t.id = t2.id
 order by t2.times desc
```

Comment: Ok i will try this man!, :D , so t2 is like the virtual columns?

Comment: @MonchoChavez Yeas it is.

Comment: But keep in mind that, like you said, this would be costly to the rdbms. So you should improve your data normalization like @Havenard said. `1-N` You will have your data better stored and much easier to get.

Comment: Ok for this new table , if i understand right. i need a row for each action?? .. right??  so i do not face again two times in two columns.. i will look for a notifications table reference.

Comment: Exatly. It will be table1( id, some other fields) table2 (id, idtable1FK, time) then you can have much more than only 5 times to every ID. and this way you could tdo a select joining then like `select table1.id, table2.time from table1, table2 where table1.id = table2.idtable1FK order by table2.time desc`

Comment: It was even simplier than that and just take 3 hours to develop the change :D wich was pretty great, know i have all the info about the notification.. im just deciding where does active has to change.. if is where the user clic notification or when he "loads" the page refering anyway. this question is solved thannks for your advaice.